# Enable SSL connection for Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I use this command to install and enable Kubernetes dashboard on a remote host:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.6.1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml


kubectl proxy --address='192.168.1.132' --port=8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'

http://192.168.1.132:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/login
```

But I get:

```
Insecure access detected. Sign in will not be available. Access Dashboard securely over HTTPS or using localhost. Read more here .
```

Is it possible to enable SSL connection on the Kubernetes host so that I can access it without this warning message and enable login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the service definition

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Which exposes port 443 (aka https). So it's already preconfigured. First, use https instead of http in your URL.

Then, instead of doing a `kubectl proxy`, why not simply

```
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard services/kubernetes-dashboard 8001:443
```

Access endpoint via https://127.0.0.1:8001/#/login

Now it's going to give the typical "certificate not signed" since the certificate are self signed (arg `--auto-generate-certificates` in deployment definition). Just skip it with your browser. See an article like https://vmwire.com/2022/02/07/running-kubernetes-dashboard-with-signed-certificates/ if you need to configure a signed certificate.

Comment: Where I need to enter this `yml` configuration?

Comment: Nowhere, it's from what you're applying (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.6.1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml)

Comment: You simply need to do `kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard services/kubernetes-dashboard 8001:443` and then access the dashboard via  https://127.0.0.1:8001/#/login

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First do a port forward to your computer, this will forward 8443 of your computer (first port) to the 8443 port in the pod (the one that is exposed acording to the manifest)

```
kubectl port-forward pod/kubernetes-dashboard 8443:8443 # Make sure you switched to the proper namespace
```

In your browser go to `http://localhost:8443` based on the error message it should work.

if the kubernetes dashboard pod implements ssl in its web server then go to `https://localhost:8443`